# Function that can return a value and also act as an object

Tags: javascript

This question seems hard to form so I will just provide an example of what I am trying to accomplish::

```
function test(word) {
    return word
}

function replaceWord(word) {
    return word
}
test('Hello').replaceWord('World')
```

So I want to be able to return "Hello" and if I want to, chain the replaceWord function.

Comparable to how jquery handles things like

```
$('#element').something('doit').somethingElse();
```

I feel like I am on the right track with

```
var test = function (word) {
    return word;
}
test.prototype = {
    replaceWord: function (word) {
        return word;
    }
}
```

But since I am returning the string, the chain will not work. What is the proper way I am supposed to doing this to be be able to have a function that can return a value [test('Hello')] and also can act as an object to modify data for value/s returned by the function [test('Hello').replaceWord('World')] leaving the value at 'World'?

Comment: You could add `replaceWord` to the `String` prototype. Though I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It’s impossible to return a plain value (without a wrapper or extra properties) that’s chainable in that way. This is especially true for strings, as they’re primitives and can’t have their own properties. jQuery accomplishes this by making everything a wrapper, along the lines of:

```
function test(word) {
    this.word = word;
}

test.prototype.next = function (word) {
    this.word = word;
    return this;
};

// or, if next() shouldn’t modify its context

test.prototype.next = function (word) {
    return new test(word);
};
```

and then

```
test.prototype.get = function () {
    return this.word;
};
```

to unwrap the wrapper. You’d use it as:

```
new test('Hello').next('World').get();
```

To drop the `new` like jQuery,

```
function test(word) {
    if (!(this instanceof test)) {
        return new test(word);
    }

    this.word = word;
}
```

Comment: This seems like the right answer. Let me give it a test and i'll be back

Comment: Strings are primitives, and it's true that they can't have properties, but the auto-boxing semantics of the language make that almost invisible.

Comment: @Pointy: You mean `new String(…)`? That’s very, very far from invisible, e.g. `test('Hello') == test('Hello')` being false, or when you prefer `===`, or producing strange results in `console.log`, or not working well with other libraries that use `typeof`, or the empty string being truthy….

Comment: @U2744SNOWFLAKE no, you can do things like `"1233".match(/foo/)` directly because a string on the left side of the `.` or `[ ]` operator will implicitly be converted to a String instance. You therefore (with some wrinkles, of course) have access to the String prototype from string primitives; at least, it seems like you do if you don't stop and think about it.

Comment: @Pointy: Oh, I figured extending the prototype was out. (Unless you’re talking about properties in general, but I did specify “own properties” (and would’ve written “can’t have own properties” if it didn’t sound so strange).)

Comment: Same goes for numbers and booleans, though with numbers it's complicated by the token grammar (which involves `.`). *edit* and yes the OP seems to dislike that (and most people would applaud that attitude :)

Comment: Is there any way to make the get() implicit? As in always get when another object is not chained to the original function?

Comment: @Runthis: No; there’s no distinction between a method that’s called in a chain or at some later point in JavaScript (except by parsing `arguments.callee` or something, which is disgusting). You can make an implicit conversion to string by implementing `toString` or to other primitive types by implementing `valueOf`, but those won’t work consistently (`==` will work, `===` won’t, for example).

Answer (score 2):

Some ideas:

- Add the methods to the object the returned value inherits from.

  ```js
  function test(word) {
      return word;
  }
  String.prototype.replaceWord = function(word) {
      return word;
  }
  test('Hello'); // 'Hello'
  test('Hello').replaceWord('World'); // 'World'
  ```

  However, modifying objects you didn't create (`String.prototype`) is not recommended.

  Also, it won't work if `test` returns `undefined` or `null`.
- Subclass the object the returned value inherits from.

  ```
  function myString(str) {
      this._value = str;
  }
  myString.prototype = Object.create(String.prototype);
  myString.prototype.constructor = myString;
  myString.prototype.toString = myString.prototype.valueOf = function() {
      return this._value;
  };
  function test(word) {
      return new myString(word);
  }
  myString.prototype.replaceWord = function(word) {
      return word;
  }
  test('Hello') + ''; // 'Hello'
  test('Hello').replaceWord('World'); // 'World'
  ```

  Here `test` can't return a literal string, but returns an object which behaves close to a string object.

  Note this may not work on some browsers.
- Use a wrapper, and retrieve the value at the end

  ```
  function Chain(value) {
      this.value = value;
  }
  Chain.prototype.replaceWord = function(word) {
      this.value = word;
      return this;
  }
  function test(word) {
      return new Chain(word);
  }
  test('Hello').value; // "Hello"
  test('Hello').replaceWord('World').value; // "World"
  ```

  In this case, the functions don't directly return the value (you must retreve it) but it's the most flexible.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure what you are ultimately trying to accomplish, but perhaps this might help:

```
Object.prototype.next = function(word) { return word; }

test('Hello') // "Hello"
test('Hello').next('World') // "World"
```

Comment: I edited the question to be more relevant to what I am trying to accomplish. There should be a better way to do this without modifying the String.prototype, especially if I may return an array, an object or even a function.

Comment: @Runthis Changed 'String' to 'Object'.

Answer (score 1):

The trick with a system like jQuery is that the *first* function builds an object of some particular type and returns that. The prototype of that object is where the subsequent "chain" methods are located. It's important that all of those methods cooperate with the scheme and return the same object (or a transformed version of that object). That's why the basic pattern for a jQuery method is (roughly):

```
$.fn.someMethod = function() {
  return this.each(function() {
    // do something
  });
};
```

The `.each()` method inside is itself a cooperative jQuery method, so it returns `this` (which, unlike in jQuery *callbacks*, is a reference to the jQuery object and not a DOM element).  Thus, by dutifully returning the jQuery object, the chain can be continued.

Note that some jQuery methods, by their very nature, can't follow that rule. A familiar example is `.val()` called with no parameters. That function returns the "value" property of the first DOM element in the jQuery object list, and since that's a string (or `undefined`) you can't chain after that.

Exactly how you'd construct a similar system largely depends on your own needs and your own design preferences, but that's the idea: a class of objects with methods that cooperate to make method chaining work.

As to your concern about how you can have the chainable methods work for string values directly, the answer is you can't if you're unwilling to modify the String prototype. It's a similar situation faced by jQuery, one that everybody using the library has to get used to: a jQuery object is **not** a DOM element; it's a wrapper.  To explicitly get to a wrapped DOM element, it has to be unwrapped.

Answer (score 0):

Return an object with a .toString method defined instead of returning a string directly.

```
function test(word) {
    return {
        word,
        replaceWord(word) {
            this.word = word;
            return this;
        },
        toString() {
            return this.word;
        }
    }
}
```

The resulting value is an object, but can be used as a string in most places, or can be cast explicitly in other cases:

```
// cases where string must be explicit
var str = String(test("Hello").replace("World"));

// other cases in which string cast is implicit
var str = `message: ${test("Hello").replace("World")}`;
var str = "message: " + test("Hello").replace("World");
```

If you are working with numeric data, `valueOf` might be more appropriate, rather than `toString` (or maybe both in odd cases).  With `valueOf` implemented, you can do something like:

```
var num = 3 + test(32).replaceNumber(16);
```